# np.random.choice has a gap in histogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am using np.random.choice to construct a histogram of the sum of throwing 2 evenly weighted dice. However, when I run the code, the values for 7, which should have the most returns, are missing.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
z = 1/6
x = np.random.choice(values, 1000000, p=[z, z, z, z, z, z])
y = np.random.choice(values, 1000000, p=[z, z, z, z, z, z])

plt.hist(x + y, 12, color="green", edgecolor='black', linewidth=1.2, label="Uniform Dist", rwidth=.75)
plt.show()
```

[image: np.random.choice: sum for 2 dice]

Any suggestions on what is going wrong?

Comment: There are no values inthe interval `6.167 <= x < 7.`. The numbers `7` are included in the interval `7.0 <= 7.833`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest So how do I close the gap?

Comment: Chose the intervals to be symmectric around the whole numbers.

Comment: You are asking for 12 bins, but only the numbers 2-12 are possible when you add these lists. Try changing the bins to 10.

Comment: Did u check that len(x+y == 7) is indeed 0?

Comment: not 10, but 11 bins are needed

Comment: Yes, you are correct @JohanC, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no values inthe interval `6.167 <= x < 7.0`. The numbers `7` are included in the interval `7.0 <= x < 7.833`.

I'd recommend to plot a bar plot of the discrete frequencies.

```
plt.bar(*np.unique(x+y, return_counts=True))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `plt.hist` binning algorithm is suitable for *real* values, not for *integer* (discrete) values.

#### Explanation

Let's see bins proposed by matplotlib:

```py
n, bins, _ = plt.hist(x + y, bb, color="green", edgecolor='black', linewidth=1.2, label="Uniform Dist", rwidth=.75)
```

The `bins` is:

```py
array([ 2.        ,  2.83333333,  3.66666667,  4.5       ,  5.33333333,
        6.16666667,  7.        ,  7.83333333,  8.66666667,  9.5       ,
       10.33333333, 11.16666667, 12.        ])
```

Sixth bar has range `[bins[5], bins[6])` equal to `[6.17, 7.00)` - notice, that it is half-open. Therefore *no* integer belongs to this range.

#### Solution

The solution is to manually set bins:

```py
values = x + y
bins = np.arange(np.min(values) - .5, np.max(values) + 0.5, 1)

plt.hist(values, bins, color="green", edgecolor='black', linewidth=1.2, label="Uniform Dist", rwidth=.75)
```

`bins` is equal to `array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, ..., 10.5, 11.5, 12.5])`.